# Scheduling DB script that update entries once a day

Tags: oracle, jobs, schedule

What is the most efficient way for scheduling DB script updating entries that are missing an attribute. Entries inserted into DB sometimes miss an attribute, I want to schedule something like sql script that checks specified entries and update them once a day based on existing db table.
I am using Oracle DB 19c version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to me, it looks as if "the most efficient" way is also "the only" way - a **stored procedure** (which updates those *entries*) which is being **scheduled** (by `dbms_scheduler`).

Let's presume that procedure is named `p_update_entries`. I won't be guessing its code.

You'd then schedule it e.g. as

```
BEGIN
   DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
      job_name         => 'p_update_entries',
      job_type         => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action       => 'BEGIN p_update_entries; end;',
      start_date       =>
         TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ ('25.08.2023 09:00 Europe/Zagreb',
                          'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi TZR'),
      repeat_interval  =>
         'FREQ=DAILY; BYDAY=MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI; BYHOUR=2; BYMINUTE=0',
      enabled          => TRUE,
      comments         => 'Fixing missing entries');
END;
/
```

It means that procedure would run every day from Monday to Friday (i.e. wouldn't run on weekends) at 02:00 in the morning. See documentation for more info about it if you think you can't adjust it according to your needs.

---

Are there other options? Theoretically, yes - you could run the procedure manually.

Database trigger wouldn't probably help as you want to do it *once a day*, while triggers fire *right now*, every time something changes in the underlying table.

I can't think of any other option; someone else might, though.